# Can I run Google ga.js and Google analytics.js for same tracking ID?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Can I run Google's `ga.js` and Google's `analytics.js` for the same tracking ID but from a different domain? Eg:

mydomain1.com (live site) using `'ga.js'` for tracking ID `UA-123456-1`

mydomain2.com (test site) using `'analytics.js'` for the same tracking ID  `UA-123456-1`

Some background info: ga.js is running on the live site, while analytics.js is running on a test server which will be used for a couple of months to do usability testing. Tracking is important for both the live and test site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do have some sites with the classic implementation (ga.js) and the GTM using universal (analytics.js) at the same time and there are no problems even though this is discouraged by the documentation.

This [video about upgrading to universal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tZIBg7vM-I) might also help: